# Configure MTA in Debian Jessie (8)

Tags: debian, logs, exim

I try to Configure MTA for the Debian Jessie (8) and followed the procedure,

`A.` `Exim4` is installed by default on Debian installations, but not configured.

Execute this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

It opens a  box where there are 4 options listed and I choose the 1st one tells `Internet site: the mail is sent and received directly by SMTP`

`B.` Make sure to create a working configuration. Send a test e-mail to yourself to make sure that the configuration works:

```
mail me@example.org
Subject: email test

test test
.
Cc:
```

Afterwards, I sent a test email as mentioned above and the command executes OK. I have also tried the command,

```
echo "test message" | mail -s "test message" user@domain.com
```

This goes also fine.

`C.` Check `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` to see the results of your test.

How would I check the `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` to see the result of the test? I can open the file using the command of, `sudo gedit /var/log/exim4/mainlog` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any way that allows you to see the file's contents will work. Unix/Linux log files are generally plain ASCII text files.

Your solution of `sudo gedit /var/log/exim4/mainlog` is valid, although overkill if you don't actually plan editing the log. You might use something like `sudo less /var/log/exim4/mainlog` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the  command to see the last email in Debian?

Comment: If you mean the log entries created by the mail, the most recent ones will be at the end of the file: each new log entry is appended to the end of the file. Reading the actual email is best done with your MUA of choice: the most bare-bones way would be to start `mail` without any arguments, then select the most recent message by typing its number and "p".

Comment: Could you please give the command? Not very familiar with Linux and started only today :)

Comment: Type `mail` and press Enter. it will display its version number, then the location of the mailbox file (typically `/var/mail/<your username>`) and the total number of emails in it. Then it displays a list of emails in your mailbox. On the last line, there will be a `&` prompt. If you want the latest email, type the same number as the number of messages in your inbox (on the 2nd line of `mail`  command output) and press Enter. The email will be displayed one screenful at a time, press space to see more. Once you see the `&` prompt again, type `x` and Enter to exit the `mail` command.